# Regex to restrict special characters in the beginning of an email address

Tags: c#, regex

PFB the regex. I want to make sure that the regex should not contain any special character just after @ and just before. In-between it can allow any combination.

The regex I have now:

```
@"^[^\W_](?:[\w.-]*[^\W_])?@(([a-zA-Z0-9]+)(\.))([a-zA-Z]{2,3}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$"))"
```

For example, the regex should not match

```
abc@.sj.com
abc@-.sj-.com
SSDFF-SAF@-_.SAVAVSAV-_.IP
```

Comment: Insert a `\b` after `^`. Not sure if you need to account for `_` though. You might also consider replacing the first `[\w-\.]+` with `[^\W_][\w.-]*` then.

Comment: It works for every special symbol except _. I need to include that as well @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: Then see my answer. As I commented, replace the first `[\w-\.]+` with `[^\W_][\w.-]*`.

Comment: A hint on formatting: to insert a code snippet, use backticks `\``. \`code\` will be displayed as `code`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you consider `_` special, I'd recommend using `[^\W_]` at the beginning and then rearrange the starting part a bit. To prevent a special char before a `@`, just make sure there is a letter or digit there. I also recommend to remove redundant capturing groups/convert them into non-capturing:

```
@"^[^\W_](?:[\w.-]*[^\W_])?@(?:\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.|(?:[\w-]+\.)+)(?:[a-zA-Z]{2,3}|[0-9]{1,3})\]?$"
```

[Here is a demo](https://regex101.com/r/yEyjL3/2) of how this regex matches now.

The `[^\W_](?:[\w.-]*[^\W_])?` matches:

- `[^\W_]` - a digit or a letter only
- `(?:[\w.-]*[^\W_])?` - a 1 or 0 occurrences of:

  - `[\w.-]*`  - 0+ letters, digits, `_`, `.` and `-`
  - `[^\W_]` - a digit or a letter only

Comment: But it is restricting email address a!bc@site.com .. I should only restrict special charcters at the beginning

Comment: @ArpitaDutta Your regex does not allow `!` in the user name either. Why use such a restrictive pattern at all then? Use `@"^\S+@\S+\.\S+$"`

Comment: I have fully answered your current question. If you made a mistake in the description, please edit. Include the real requirements and sample valid/invalid emails.

Comment: @ArpitaDutta: See my adjusted solution and the [demo](https://regex101.com/r/yEyjL3/2).

Comment: I have explained the pattern in my answer. What exactly do you need to understand? No need to post questions like "explain me what the pattern means", they will all be closed as dupes of What does this pattern mean.

Comment: i want to validate an email address that must not start with any special character plus this should not contain any special character just after @ or   before . Also the regex should be able to validate an email abc@mit-liner.com @wiktorStribizew

Comment: Re-read what you wrote: "this should not contain any special character just after @ or before" - I understand that the email should NOT contain any non-digit and non-letter. And then you say "Also the regex should be able to validate an email abc@mit-liner.com" - which invalidates what you wrote before. So, please explain what part should contain what characters.

Comment: I wrote "This should not contain any special character immediately after (@ )or just before (.) . i.e. abc@#sjg%.com should be invalidated. But if any special charcter exist between (@) and  (.) , it must be preceded and succeded by numbers/charcters

Comment: Ok, try [`^[\w-[_]](?:[\w.-]*[\w-[_]])?@(?:[\w-[_]]+\.)+[\w-[_]]+$`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%5b%5cw-%5b_%5d%5d%28%3f%3a%5b%5cw.-%5d*%5b%5cw-%5b_%5d%5d%29%3f%40%28%3f%3a%5b%5cw-%5b_%5d%5d%2b%5c.%29%2b%5b%5cw-%5b_%5d%5d%2b%5cr%3f%24&i=abc%40.sj.com%0d%0aabc%40-.sj-.com%0d%0aSSDFF-SAF%40-_.SAVAVSAV-_.IP%0d%0aabc%40site.com%0d%0a.abc%40site.com%0d%0a_abc%40site.com%0d%0a9abc%40site.com%0d%0a9abc.%40site.com%0d%0aa%40site.com%0d%0a!%40site.com%0d%0aa!%40site.com&o=m) The `[\w-[_]]` = `[^\W_]` but is a positive character class where we can add more characters that we want to match.

Comment: BTW, to allow a hyphen, replace `\.` with `[-.]`. [Here is another .NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%5b%5cw-%5b_%5d%5d%28%3f%3a%5b%5cw.-%5d*%5b%5cw-%5b_%5d%5d%29%3f%40%28%3f%3a%5b%5cw-%5b_%5d%5d%2b%5b-.%5d%29%2b%5b%5cw-%5b_%5d%5d%2b%5cr%3f%24&i=abc%40.sj.com%0d%0aabc%40-.sj-.com%0d%0aSSDFF-SAF%40-_.SAVAVSAV-_.IP%0d%0aabc%40site.com%0d%0a.abc%40site.com%0d%0a_abc%40site.com%0d%0a9abc%40site.com%0d%0a9abc.%40site.com%0d%0aa%40site.com%0d%0a!%40site.com%0d%0aabc%40mit-liner.com&o=m). Also, do you need to only allow ASCII or ALL UNICODE letters/digits? You haven't mentioned it.

Comment: While you are trying out the above suggestions, here is an ASCII only regex version of the above one: `^[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])?@(?:[a-zA-Z0-9]+[-.])+[a-zA-Z0-9]+$`

Comment: @Arpita, please check my comments, and let me know if that is what you need. Maybe you need to use `[a-zA-Z]{2,3}` at the end (Unicode equivalent - `\p{L}{2,3}`).

Comment: this my regex "[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&' * +/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?" with this regex it accept ")]=}!><$%+./|" how can i delete all those from regex forma especially for the end of the mail

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew you should definitely post your latest version here instead of just in the "demo" link in your previous answer as it will surely be lost after a while. This definiltely answer my every needs for email validation. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Change the initial `[\w-\.]+` for `[A-Za-z0-9\-\.]+`.

Note that this excludes many acceptable email addresses.

**Update**

As pointed out, `[A-Za-z0-9]` is not an exact translation of `\w`.  However, you appear to have a specific definition as to what you consider special characters and so it is probably easier for you to define within the square brackets what you class as allowable.

Comment: In .NET, [`\w`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/character-classes-in-regular-expressions#WordCharacter) matches  `[\p{Ll}\p{Lu}\p{Lt}\p{Lo}\p{Lm}\p{Mn}\p{Nd}\p{Pc}]`, not `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`.